# Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray() returning null in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ftp, bitmapfactory

So I am downloading an image from an FTP server and then trying to save it locally on my android device.  The code I am using has worked before and with no changes that should affect how it downloads and processes images it has randomly stopped working.  The stream fills the byte array just fine but for whatever reason bitmapfactory cannot decode it.  It is a normal image file that happens to have spaces and number signs in its title, but that should not have any effect.  Here's the relevant code:

```
        BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(dataSocket.InputStream);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            input.Read(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        if (ASCII)
        {
            String result = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(savePath, result);
        } else
        {
            Bitmap bm = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savePath);
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat format = null;
            String extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);
            switch (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename))
            {
                case ".jpg":
                case ".jpeg":
                case ".jpe":
                    format = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
                case ".png":
                case ".bmp":
                case ".gif":
                case ".tif":
                case ".tiff":
                    format = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png;
                    break;
            }
            bm.Compress(format, 100, System.IO.File.OpenWrite(savePath));
            //BufferedOutputStream fileOut = new BufferedOutputStream(System.IO.File.OpenWrite(savePath));
            //fileOut.Write(buffer);
            //fileOut.Flush();
            //fileOut.Close();
        }
```

A null reference exception fires at the line bm.Compress(format... due to BitMapFactory.DecodeByteArray() returning null.  I can't figure out why it randomly started doing this after working before.  It has actually worked then started returning null then started working again then stopped working again, yet I have no idea what I could've changed that would've affected anything.

Comment: Could you be loosing some data while downloading the file and this is why BitmapFactory is having problems decoding the byteArray? Try verifying all data is in the buffer.

Comment: `downloading an image from an FTP server and then trying to save it locally`. Well then why would you use BitmapFactory or trying to mess around with a Bitmap? Very bad idea. You will get a file from the ftp server. So just save the received bytes to file. Thats all. Dont mess around.

Comment: Also for the ASCII part your code is strange. You should just write the received bytes to file. Thats all. You also dont need different code for ascii or image or what other types of file. One code to save the received bytes to file will do for all types of files.

Comment: I actually ended up getting it to work by using DecodeStream on the data socket's stream instead of saving the bytes to a buffer then trying to decode them.  However, just saving the bytes to a file would definitely be simpler so I'll look into that when I go back into work.  Thanks for the advice @greenapps